# Background ReSize with browser with FULL image

Tags: css, background

Okay so when create say an image for a background say of a box well I need the image size COMPLETELY full image to resize COMPLETLY with the browser I cant seem to make an image stay as a background fully all corners to the browser window no matter what size. I don't care about stretching I can fix this in photoshop.... I cannot seem to figure out this problem with CSS, and I need to.. Seems so simple, yet so difficult. Thanks! I looked at some tips on the Net but nothing really helps I put an image as a BG and the corner or the top and bottom will be partially missing... I need it to fit with the browser window

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: in CSS try `body,html{height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;} ` and your div with bkg `div{background:url( '''); background-size:cover; width:100%;height:100%;}`

Comment: Try this site: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: its not my div that has a Background its the page under body..like       

body {
     background: url('bgimage.png')
     background-size: cover;   ////don't know exactly how to cover the paGE AND resize with browser not cutting away as it gets bigger or smaller/////

div1 {
     .........
     .......

}
div2 {
.....
.......
}


you get the idea
}